# Architecture for Building an iPhone/Mobile Web App

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, css, mobile

I wanted some peer advice as far as how to build out a web app for the iPhone.

Are these the basic concepts?

1. Issue all of the HTML/CSS for all mobile views on the initial load
2. Use JavaScript/jQuery to scroll to each view when buttons are pressed
3. Use AJAX requests to populate data for each view (before or after the scrolling occurs)

Part of me thinks using something like iUI may be a little overkill.

Comment: jQuery Mobile also might be worth looking into http://jquerymobile.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [what's the best practices for building a mobile/tablet-compatible web app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042725/whats-the-best-practices-for-building-a-mobile-tablet-compatible-web-app)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that this is an exact duplicate - there may be some more illuminating answers yet to come - but there are some links in [this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042725/whats-the-best-practices-for-building-a-mobile-tablet-compatible-web-app/6043551#6043551) that might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at JQTOUCH, jQuery Mobile, DHTMLX Touch framework, Wink, NimbleKit and The M Project.  I'm sure you can google these for more info.

If its for the iPhone (and thats all you want NOW) and you know Javascript pretty well.  I'd just go with Titanium.

http://www.appcelerator.com/

Later on you can always build a HTML5 web app when things have matured.  I don't think they have as it stands now.